# d3 v4 pie with minimum arc length/width

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a generic pie chart with d3 v4.
Sometimes the data is creating a very small arc which seems like a very thin line.

as in the following example: [image].

the code which generates this chart is:

```
this.pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value((d) => {
    if (this.allValuesZero) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return d.value;
    }
  })
  .startAngle(-90 * (pi / 180))
  .endAngle(90 * (pi / 180));

this.arc = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 3)
  .innerRadius(radius - 12)
  .cornerRadius(9)
  .padAngle(.05);
```

How can I manipulate the length before it is being rendered?

Comment: make sure your `value` is at least x% of the total. But this gives a distorted picture of the actual value (Oh it is not very small)

Comment: I cannot assure that, it should display the data as it was given but with a small exception - if it is lower than X the size should look like a circle

Comment: there is no space to draw the circle (rounded arc segment) because the rounding circles are **inside** the arc, and the pie angle for this value is to small to draw the circle so it will overlap the padding.